# SSLHandshakeException in Mail Sending Code

Tags: java, security, email, sslhandshakeexception

I am developing code for sending email from my domain to gmail.com

I get a `SSLHandshakeException` (see below).
How to Solve this??

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Is there any firewall settings on your server?

Comment: Comment in the answer to this question might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743846/unable-to-send-an-email-using-smtp-getting-javax-mail-messagingexception-could

Answer (score -1):

You are not using SSL, you are trying to send the mail in plain authentication, while you need a an SSL authenticated access.