# Got bad greeting from SMTP host: smtp.yandex.ru, port: 465, response: [EOF]] with root cause Yandex

Tags: spring, email, smtp, yandex

I use brand new spring boot project with next Maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Implementation of method

```
 @Autowired
JavaMailSender emailSender;

@GetMapping("/send")
public String send() {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom("some-name@domain.com");
    message.setTo("toReceiver@gmail.com");
    message.setSubject(null);
    message.setText("Hello World");
    emailSender.send(message);
    return "success send email " + now();
}
```

application.yml

```
host: smtp.yandex.ru
username: some-name@domain.io
password: password
port: 465
```

And receive the next exception

```
2020-08-03 23:02:35.102 ERROR 21615 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: smtp.yandex.com, port: 465, response: [EOF].
```

`Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: smtp.yandex.com, port: 465, response: [EOF]; message exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: smtp.yandex.com, port: 465, response: [EOF]] with root cause`

But the same code works perfectly with [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io) service

According to this [link](http://settings.su/yandex)  I used not secure 25 port
After which I received the next exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.yandex.ru, 25; timeout -1;
```

587 port =

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [EOF];
```

I guess a problem with SSL

Similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743846/unable-to-send-an-email-using-smtp-getting-javax-mail-messagingexception-could)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This properties help me

```
spring:
 boot:
   admin:
     mail:
       to: ${spring.mail.username}, test@yandex.ru
       from: ${spring.mail.username} 
 mail:
   host: smtp.yandex.ru
   username: test@yandex.ru
   password: password
   port: 587
   protocol: smtp
   properties:
     "mail.transport.protocol": smtp
     "mail.smtp.auth": true
     "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": true
```

Answer (score 24):

With port: 465 (SMTP Protocol), you can try enable ssl via properties:

**"mail.smtp.ssl.enable": true**

```
mail.smtp.ssl.enable: If set to true, use SSL to connect and use the SSL port by default. Defaults to false for the "smtp" protocol and true for the "smtps" protocol.
```

Using spring boot, add properties to application.yml:

```
 mail:
   ...
   properties:
     "mail.smtp.ssl.enable": true
```

References:

```
Outgoing mail
mail server address — smtp.yandex.com
connection security — SSL
port — 465
```

The SMTP protocol provider supports the following properties:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Comment: Additional the "message from" address need to be the same as username in mail configuration. So "some-name@domain.com" need to be changed to: "some-name@domain.io" to be exact the same as in `application.yml` config.

Answer (score 0):

In this question asked for port 465 , I am using same port 465 then same error come so if you are want to use port 465 then use this

If your mail server supports SSL/TLS on port 465, you can use it for secure email transmission.
Ensure that your Java code is configured to use SSL/TLS.

```
   You've correctly set properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); in your 
   previous Java code.
```

and if you want to use port 587 then Ensure that your Java code is correctly configured for either SSL/TLS or STARTTLS, depending on the port you are using.
For STARTTLS, you may need to set

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); in addition to other settings.
```